# Selenium SendKeys not working for open brackets and harsh keys when using java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have using selenium webdriver 2.33.0 and i have a requirement of sending data with the following characters inside the data `("(", "#")`

When we tried to send these characters using sendkeys

```
"WebElement dat = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathexpression);
dat.sendkeys("select * from (?s, ?p, ?o)");
```

The following data gets displayed in the textarea as `select * from ?s, ?p, ?o)`
the open bracket is missing. I have used selenium actions class sendkeys and robot sendkeys also.

I am not able to fix the issue. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you let us know if the following string is giving the same error? `"select * from"+" (?s, ?p, ?o)"`

Comment: A good debugging tip would be to use Javascript to put the same thing into the text box. If the same thing happens with Javascript, Selenium is not at fault.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved when using actions class

```
WebElement dat = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathexpression"); 
dat.click(); 
Actions data = new Actions(driver);
data.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a"),Keys.DELETE);
data.perform();
query = query.replaceAll("\\(", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,"9")); 
query = query.replaceAll("\\#", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,"3")); 
query = query.replaceAll("\\-", Keys.SUBTRACT.toString()); 
query = query.replaceAll("\\}", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,"]")); 
data.sendKeys(query); 
data.perform();
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but efficient workaround: replace the opening brackets `(` with the key sequence `shift + 9`, as suggested by user2935099.

```
dat.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "9"));
```

Funnily, this seems to work regardless of your current keyboard layout (I use an Irish locale with a French layout).

---

I stumbled upon this one with version 2.40.0, and it is definitely a bug in Selenium. Using the following in the Firefox JavaScript console works flawlessly:

```
 var box = getElementById('SearchBox');
 box.setValue('AB (CDE FGH)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried entering the same thing with my selenium setup and it worked fine in both `firefox` and `chrome`. I am not not very sure about the reason but one thing that I can notice that you are using very old selenium version(`2.33.0`) currently `2.37.0` is available. May be you should try updating the selenium and t should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks DigVijay. I am facing the same issue after upgrading to selenium java 2.37.0.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, using `2.40.0` my workaorund was using clipboard, not pretty but testsystems have not much use for a clipboard anyway...

```
public static void setTextByClipboard(WebElement element, String text) {
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(text);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection, selection);
    element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
}
```